# How can I approximate the accurate sensor readings given readings from noisy sensors?

Tags: variance, repeated-measures, validation, cross-correlation, measurement

I have five sensors measuring the same quantities (temperature, humidity, barometric pressure) at the same time. I also have reference measurements (from much more accurate sensors).

What is the appropriate approach to validate the output of the five sensors in terms of how well they agree with each other and with the reference measurements?

I have zero statistical background, only a problem to solve!

Comment: Is it sufficient to just use the mean squared error? Assuming you have the more accurate sensors already...

Comment: I could do that but I thought that would be specific to the sensors I'm using and not a general study of the sensors. The idea is that I want to use the cheaper (less accurate) sensors instead of the more accurate ones in the future but I want to know how reliable and good (in terms of precision, accuracy) they are. 
Ther was a similar question wherein the answers pointed towards some variance analysis (ANOVA) - I don't know if that's what I need or how to do it (yet).

Answer (score 1):

I would use the reference measurements to calibrate the other sensors' biases:
$$x_{ij}=s_{i}+\mu_j+\varepsilon_{ij},$$
where $x_{ij}$ - measured value from sensor $j$, $s_{i}$ - true value, $\mu_j$ - bias and $\varepsilon_{ij}$ - random error.

We don't know the true value $s_i$, but we can use the reference sensors $r$ assuming they have no bias and small errors $u$:
$$r_{i}=s_{i}+u_{i}$$

Plug one equation to another, and take the expectation:
$$\mu_j = E[x_{ij}-r_{i}]\approx \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n x_{ij}-r_{i}$$

Once you know the bias, you can use it to get the best measurement estimate:
$$\hat s_i=\frac 1 m \sum_{j=1}^m x_{ij}-\mu_j$$

You can get more sophisticated but you need to keep the focus on what matters most. Your main issue is the bias, once you figure out how to deal with it, the stochastic errors will be averaged out by multiple sensor measurements. Consider a case where all sensors have the same bias: $\mu_j=\mu$

This is the worst case scenario, and you have no way to correct it without the reference sensors, unlike the stochastic errors that will be reduced or eliminated by repeated measurements.

Comment: Thanks! So, the bias $\mu_j$ of sensor `j` is the average difference (or error)  compared to the more accurate sensor. This allows me to get the best measurement estimate for a given sensor. 
How do I compare the different sensors? And I want to use a correlation function to estimate what the mroe accurate sensor would read given the reading for the less accurate sensor (if such a relationship exists). E.g. if the less accurate sensor is always 50% of the reading with a small itercept.

Comment: Why would the sensors be correlated? I mean their stochastic parts. Obviously, the measurements are correlated because they're measuring the same thing $s$.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not explaining my problem in the correct terms. The more accurate sensor (D) and less accurate sensor (B) are being tested together for now. Eventually, I will use only one sensor B per experiment. My goal was to see if there is a function like $D = c_0 + c_1 \times B$ using which I could estimate what D would measure for a given setup while only using B. This is because there are some other models that are based on data from D. Also I want to evaluate how well the less accurate sensors (B) agree with each other. For either sensor type (B, D), I have the mfg. reported accuracy %.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your question is something like, how can I approximate the accurate sensor readings given my noisy sensors. Which, if that's true, you really need to rewrite your question as it is rather confusing. @Aksakal's answer would give you a way of seeing what the bias of each sensor is, but I don't really see how that helps you.

One simple method would be linear regression: Assume the errors are independent in time and then try to predict the correct sensor values as a linear combination of your noisy ones.

My second suggestion would be to use the fact that you have a ground truth sensor to fit the parameters of a Kalman filter and use that.

Comment: Thanks! That is definitely a big part of my question, the other part is to see how well the noisy sensors agree with each other and if their behaviour is repeatable i.e. would the approximation (of more accurate sensor reading given the noisy sensor) hold for other noisy sensors that I want to use.

Comment: In general? I suppose you could attempt to train the same model for all your 5 sensors and see how well it performs, but you'd still have a sample size of 5. There is no way to ask how it performs for "other sensors" unless you have more sensors to test with, for sure.